# Occasionally missing "selected" option in dropdowns after reload a form (Update: could reproduce the error)

Tags: html, forms, select, browser, reload

There is a large form with a list of 100-300 events per day / date. Each event in the list have 3 dropdowns for day, month and year. They are "simple" select fields, without javascript. Days, month and years are static, only the "selected" attribute is dynamically dependet on the date of the event.

```
<select name="event_m_590909" id="event_m_590909">
  <option value="0"></option>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
  <option>5</option>
  <option>6</option>
  <option>7</option>
  <option>8</option>
  <option>9</option>
  <option selected="">10</option>
  <option>11</option>
  <option>12</option>
</select>
```

The form has been in this kind for several years. Since a few weeks, a strange problem occures.

Users often press the refresh button to get the latest data. It happens sometimes, that the correct date is not selected after a reload. Sometimes only 1 or 2 (f.e. month and day) are affected, sometimes every 3 in the next row.

The problem rarely occurs and is not reproducible so far. There are always only a few events affected. The affected events seem completely arbitrary. After another reload everything is normal again.

Possible causes:

- I think a programming error is not likely, because then all events
  would be affected and a another reload should not fix the problem.
- An incomplete data transfer should also be excluded.The page will be
  loaded to the end.
- Errors in data transmission are also unlikely. It really can not be
  that only a few "option" lines are not transferred and nothing
  else.

Maybe a certain behavior of the browser is responsible? Does anyone have an idea what could be the cause?

Comment: I was able to reproduce the error, it is related to the behavior of the users. Here my procedure: Opend the form in a tab in Firefox. Notebook put to idle mode (not sure if that is strongly required), browser and tab with form remain open. The next day the form is not reloaded because the session has already expired. Opend a new tab and loged in to the application. Then switched to the tab with the form from yesterday and reload. Then i had the dropdowns which not shows the "selected" option.

Comment: I checked the source code, its OK. The correct value is "selected". Just like any other droddowns in the form. But in some drodpwons the browser just does not show the selected option.